# Trying to build flink 1.18.0 docker image using fedora:37 as base image

Tags: docker, apache-flink

When steps from here https://github.com/apache/flink-docker/blob/3154e4800c2aa8f183ac4b03dcdc90b14a6404a1/1.18/scala_2.12-java11-ubuntu/Dockerfile#L22C15-L44 are exceute

I get the below error. How do i get this fixed

```
#13 193.2 + gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 96AE0E32CBE6E0753CE6DF6CB078D1D3253A8D82
#13 193.2 gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp.9fYDMuHKOt/pubring.kbx' created
#13 203.2 gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
#13 203.2 + :
#13 203.2 + for server in ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net $(shuf -e hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 keyserver.ubuntu.com hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 pgp.mit.edu)
#13 203.2 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 96AE0E32CBE6E0753CE6DF6CB078D1D3253A8D82
#13 223.4 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#13 223.4 + :
#13 223.4 + for server in ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net $(shuf -e hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 keyserver.ubuntu.com hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 pgp.mit.edu)
#13 223.4 + gpg --batch --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 96AE0E32CBE6E0753CE6DF6CB078D1D3253A8D82
#13 287.6 gpg: keyserver receive failed: End of fill
```